# Logic Either..Or

Tags: logic, symbolic-logic

In the book: "Elementary Logic" authored by Brian Garrett, he has a few examples, one with solution and one without that conclude the following:

1) Either many people will attend the concert, or it will be cancelled
Solution: M or C

2) Either Mary goes on a diet, or she will remain obese
Solution: probably M or O

In my mind both of these would be wrong. I think the solution is a tad more complicated because the implication of both doesn't make sense. I think the answer should exclude the situation where both are true hence:

General solution for both: (P and ~Q) or (Q and ~P)
Am I right or wrong and why? Thanks for the help I hate confusion in text books.

Comment: There is simpler notation: P ⊕ Q.

Comment: It's been empirically proven that dieting makes people fat. Every fat person has been on dozens of diets. You could look up the studies. So Mary (make sure to pick a female name for a desperately dieting fattie, note the subtle sexism) may well go on a diet and end up fatter than she was before.

Comment: @user4894, relevance?

Comment: @rus9384 OP is trying to use examples where xor is correct and inclusive or is wrong -- AS YOU YOURSELF JUST POINTED OUT.

Comment: I can add that "either... or..." typically notates ⊕ in English. Without "either" it may not be so. "Either" is some kind of exclusiveness quantifier.

Comment: @user4894, I mean relevance of your comment where you say that diet will result in obesity.

Comment: @rus9384 Supporting evidence that OP's example is a classic example of an inclusive OR.

Comment: @user4894 - A very interesting point about dieting and sexism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**IF** the context is the usual (i.e. [truth-functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_function)) propositional calculus, the "or" particle is modelled with [Logical disjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction) and logical disjunction is *inclusive* :

> **A ∨ B** is false iff both **A** and **B** are false. In all other cases it is true.

But you have to check in your book : maybe the author explicitly asks to translate "either ... or ..." as an [exclusive disjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or), in which case you are right.

Comment: Ahead in the book he explains that in the sense of just logic then these are modeled by inclusive disjunction. Physically or metaphysically this is modeled by exclusive. However since the book is titled "Elementary logic" the context is logic therefore we should model or as inclusive disjuction

Comment: Im common speech "or", "and" and simple connection of words are used differenly. That's because there are different categories.